# How to migrate DolphinDB cluster onto another machine

Tags: database, server, migrate, dolphindb

Our company is using DolphinDB on a daily basis. As time goes by, we have too much data on our old server. So we decided to migrate our cluster onto to another Dell PowerEdge server with 128 cores. We did this by copying all the data onto the new machine, but as we started the new cluster and trying to open a dfs database by using command:

```
db = database("dfs://rangeDB");
```

it reported an error message:

```
The chunk meta returned from name node didn't contain any site.
```

How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

DolphinDB is a distributed database system. A database contains meta data on controller and chunk data on multiple data nodes. Simply copying all directory from one machine to another doesn't work.

The best practice for DolphinDB migration is to use builtin backup and restore functions. First, use `backup` function to export data to a shared disk and then use `restore` function to import data from the backup directory.